# ListView Item Selection Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want a ListView to behave like this:

**With mouse Input:**

- Left Click -> Item click event handler gets executed, but should not
  display it as "selected"
- Right Click -> Item gets selected

**With touch Input:**

- Single Tap -> equivalent to left click
- Swipe Down -> equivalent to right click

I have played around with various of the events and settings but cant seem to get it to work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want your listview to behave like the Windows Start screen?  This one was brutal for me to figure out - the mouse part was easy, but the touch part not so much.  The solution turns out to be pretty easy.  You just have to enable the right options for your listview.  Here's the xaml for mine:

```
<ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
        />
```

Sorry, I haven't figured how to get code to highlight in StackOverflow yet.

Comment: In other words, set `IsSwipeEnabled` to `True`? Lol, that's pretty easy :)

Comment: @Jase - The description from MSDN for `IsSwipeEnabled` reads: "Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the view supports discrete input processing for a swipe interaction." What does that really mean? I can laugh about it now, but it took me a few weeks to figure out. Easier for some people than others I suppose :)

Comment: I agree. I was just a bit amused because I thought it would be way more complicated to have swipe :)

Answer (score 1):

This could help you with the mouseclicks

```
 private void MainForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            method()
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            set selection = false
            method()
    }
```

and for the handle of the touch i hope this helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx